# can drawRect be triggered on a SCNView (macOS)?

Tags: macos, scenekit, drawrect

I have two macOS apps that are very similar.  One app renders an animation in 2-D, with Quartz calls, in a subclass of `NSView`, the other app, a 3-D animation in a subclass of `SCNView` (itself a subclass of `NSView`) using SceneKit geometries.  In each case the "view" is owned by a view controller and that ownership is set in a storyboard.  In each case I use a timer to dirty the view every second so its `drawRect` gets triggered to drive the animated movements.  In each case I have used: `self.view.needsDisplay = true`

In the 2-D case, `drawRect` is called in the view instance, in the 3-D case it is not (even for the initial render).

I'm puzzled!  Does `SCNView` suppress calls to `drawRect`?  If so, how might I get around this?  If not, what voodoo secret have I missed?

If this behavior is not what readers would expect, I will post a sample project which exhibits it.

*I know that SceneKit can take advantage of Core Animation but I want to keep the same general timer mechanism in both apps because the animated content is, essentially, the same action, what was flat in 2-D is spherical in 3-D so using SceneKit rendering made sense.*

Added an Xcode project to show different `NSView` and `SCNView` behaviors:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtymzitkqcqhfje/SCN.zip?dl=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're fighting the framework.

SceneKit has its own timers for rendering and animation. Hook into those to update your objects' properties (locations, colors, etc). Let SceneKit handle the draw calls.

The methods you need may be in unexpected places. Take a look at documentation for `SCNSceneRenderer` and `SCNSceneRendererDelegate` protocols. The [renderer delegate documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/scenekit/scnscenerendererdelegate) explains the render loop and shows you where to customize your app's animations and physics.

Comment: I'm using those callbacks now and accomplishing my goals, so, thank you.  I found I was doing a lot of computation in the delegate calls, some of it unnecessary because many of the objects' properties don't change that fast, so I'm incrementing a counter on every render loop but only updating 'slow' properties every 60 (or more) loops.  This feels a little kludgy but it gets the job done.  Thanks Hal